# Is anyone able to figure out why the inventory is the same for everyone?

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py

When someone uses the fish command, it does what it should, it chooses a random fish, and puts it in your 'inventory'.  Issue is, it doesn't just put it in yours, it puts it in everyone else's too. So, if I get 2 fish, so does everyone else. Also, the elif msg == 'view' inserts data anyway, it doesn't send the message saying '"You don't have any"

```
kind = []
fishes = 0
level = 1
storage = []
cash = 0
@client.command()
async def fish(ctx, *, msg: str):
    global cash
    global storage
    global level
    global kind
    global fishes
    name = ctx.author.name
    guild_id = ctx.author.guild.id
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    large_chance = ['Carp', 'Salmon', 'Frog']
    medium_chance = ['Catfish', 'Eel', 'Large Bass']
    small_chance = ['Angelfish', 'Blobfish', 'Shark']

    cursor.execute("SELECT user_id FROM fishing WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s",
                   (user_id, guild_id))
    result1 = cursor.fetchone()
    if result1 is None:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO fishing (name, user_id, guild_id, fish, kind, money, storage, level) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       (name, user_id, guild_id, fishes, kind, cash, storage, level))
        conn.commit()
    elif result1 is not None:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE fishing SET fish = %s, kind = %s, storage = %s, level = %s WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s",
                       (fishes, kind, storage, level, user_id, guild_id))
        conn.commit()
    if msg == 'fish':
        if level == 1:
            y = random.randint(0, 100)
            if y >= 30:
                small = random.choice(large_chance)
                embed = discord.Embed(title='Fishing Game',
                                      color=ctx.author.color)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name='You caught a common fish', value=f'You caught a {small}')
                embed.add_field(name="Worth:", value="$5")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                kind.append(small)
                fishes += 1
                cursor.execute("UPDATE fishing SET kind = %s, fish = %s WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s",
                               (kind, fishes, user_id, guild_id))
                conn.commit()
            elif y >= 20:
                medium = random.choice(medium_chance)
                embed = discord.Embed(title='Fishing Game',
                                      color=ctx.author.color)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name='You caught an uncommon fish', value=f'You caught a {medium}')
                embed.add_field(name="Worth:", value="$50")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                kind.append(medium)
                fishes += 1
                cursor.execute("UPDATE fishing SET kind = %s, fish = %s WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s",
                               (kind, fishes, user_id, guild_id))
                conn.commit()
            elif y <= 5:
                large = random.choice(small_chance)
                embed = discord.Embed(title='Fishing Game',
                                      color=ctx.author.color)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name='You caught a rare fish!', value=f'You caught a {large}!')
                embed.add_field(name="Worth:", value="$200")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                kind.append(large)
                fishes += 1
                cursor.execute("UPDATE fishing SET kind = %s, fish = %s WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s",
                               (kind, fishes, user_id, guild_id))
                conn.commit()
    elif msg == 'view':
        cursor.execute('SELECT fish, kind FROM fishing WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s',
                       (user_id, guild_id))
        result2 = cursor.fetchone()
        if result2 is not None:
            await ctx.send(f'You have {fishes} fish: {collections.Counter(kind)}')
        elif result2 is None:
            await ctx.send("You don't have any fish yet")
```